# recursively deleting files in x64 assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, posix, x86-64, system-calls

So i need to recursievly delete files in a directory using x86_64 assembly.
here is my code and i know it is bad. My problem is that every syscall works individualy(i can individualy delete directories or documents) , But as soon as i merge them together like this, it doesn't work . #edit: as pointed by @fuz, the question was not descriptive enough. so i want it do open directory that contains file called "test.txt", delete that file, and then to delete the directory that contained the file. But it just exits the program when i compile it with nasm. I am using Linux mint

```
global _start

section .text

_start:


;open directory
    mov rax,    2       ;sys_open
    mov rdi,    dir     ;pointer to the directory
    mov rsi,    0       ;read only
    syscall


;delete document
    mov rax,    87      ;sys_unlink
    mov rdi,    doc     ;points to the document
    syscall


;delete directory
    mov rax,    84      ;sys_rmdir
    mov rdi,    dir
    syscall


_exit:
    mov rax,    60
    mov rdi,    80
    syscall


section .data
dir: db 'test',0
doc: db 'test.txt',0
```

Comment: “It doesn't work” is not an error description.  What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?  Also, which operating system are you programming for?

Comment: @fuz  i am using Linux mint, and nothing happens. it just exist from the program. i want it to open the directory, delete the document "test.txt' in the directory and than delete the directory that contained "test.txt" file

Comment: My first piece of advice would be to check return values.  After `syscall` returns, the value in the `rax` register is the return value.  If between `-1` and `-4096`, it is the negative of an `errno` code.

Comment: (1) What is the purpose of opening the directory?  You don't do anything with the file handle you get back.  (2) `rmdir` can only delete a directory when it's empty.  (3) Paths will be understood to be relative, so you are trying to unlink `./test.txt` and then remove the directory `./test`, which doesn't match your explanation that you want to remove the directory that contains the file.

Comment: Finally, it would probably be wise to write your code in C first, get it working, and then think about how it would look in assembly.

Comment: @NateEldredge that is the reason im trying to delete the directory recursievly. 1. open directory. 2. delete the file that directory containts(in this case 'test.txt').3. delete directory that contained the file. 4 exit

Comment: @starboy Opening a directory does not change your current working directory.  This is done with `chdir` instead.  That said, there is no need for that anyway, just unlink `test/test.txt` instead.

Comment: You might also be interested in  `strace`. But doing this from assembly is pretty pointless anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not with assembly, it's with understanding basic POSIX / Unix file manipulation system calls.  `open("dir")` does not make later unlink / rmdir system calls relative to that directory, they're still relative to your current working directory.  You can change that with `chdir()`.

(And that's easier to do with C than with asm.  For most system calls, the glibc wrapper is trivial and passes on all the args unchanged to the kernel.  When that's not the case, the NOTES section of the Linux man page documents that.)

---

**There *are* system calls that do things relative to an open directory file descriptor (instead of the CWD)**, whose names add an `...at` suffix to the traditional system-call names.  The documentation uses C syntax to describe the system calls, but given the ABI this tells you how to call them in asm.

- [`unlinkat(int dirfd, const char *pathname, int flags)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html)
- fd-relative [`rmdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rmdir.2.html) is actually done with `unlinkat(fd, path, AT_REMOVEDIR)`.  (Otherwise, with `flags=0`, unlinkat behaves like regular `unlink`).
- `linkat`, `symlinkat`, `readlinkat`, `statat`, `mkdirat`, `execveat`, ...
- various others, including `renameat`, and a fun [`renameat2`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/renameat.2.html) that takes flags allowing you to atomically *swap* two pathnames on the same filesystem.
- The [notes section of the `openat` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) explains why these `at` system calls exist in the first place, under `Rationale for openat()` - avoids race conditions between readdir and open if someone else `rename`s a directory component of the path.  And since `chdir()` is per-process, not per-thread, allows different threads to do relative stuff in different directories at the same time.

---

Like Jester said, use **`strace find test -name 'test.txt' -delete`** or something like that to see how to actually recurse through directories with `open(O_DIRECTORY)`, `getdents`, and `unlinkat`.

[`getdents`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html) is the raw system call that the POSIX `readdir` interface is built on top of, on Linux.  The man pages document this.  In asm, you can either use libc function calls to `readdir`, or you'd have to use `getdents` yourself.

---

**Or since you aren't actually *recursing*, just hard-coding some relative paths, you could just make `unlink("test/test.txt")` and `rmdir("test")` system calls.**